# Jenkins SCM Sync Configuration Plugin seems to have no effect

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to save all configuration files in my Jenkins in an SCM repository. I have installed `SCM Configuration Plugin` and filled its properties this way:

[image]

But I have never got any pop-up like what [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) says while I'm trying to change projects' configurations; neither got anything committed to my SCM repository. What did I wrong? What else should I consider about this?

I have `Subversion Plug-in 2.5` and `SCM Sync Configuration Plugin 0.0.8`. This is SystemLog after updating one of the projects:

```
Mar 31, 2015 11:14:38 AM INFO com.sonyericsson.hudson.plugins.metadata.contributors.JobContributorsController onChange
Submitted to metadata-queue: hudson.model.FreeStyleProject@21973d0b[OMC_Functional_Tests]
Mar 31, 2015 11:14:38 AM WARNING hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.SCMManipulator expectScmRepositoryInitiated
SCM Repository has not yet been initiated !
Mar 31, 2015 11:14:39 AM WARNING hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.SCMManipulator expectScmRepositoryInitiated
SCM Repository has not yet been initiated !
Mar 31, 2015 11:14:39 AM WARNING hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.SCMManipulator expectScmRepositoryInitiated
SCM Repository has not yet been initiated !
Mar 31, 2015 11:14:41 AM INFO hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
Started PeriodicBackup
Mar 31, 2015 11:14:41 AM WARNING org.jenkinsci.plugins.periodicbackup.PeriodicBackup execute
Cron is not defined.
Mar 31, 2015 11:14:41 AM INFO hudson.model.AsyncPeriodicWork$1 run
Finished PeriodicBackup. 1 ms
```

I tried to authenticate the SCM as @lkisac said, but I got this stack trace:

```
Passing user name team.j1 and password you entered
Authentication was not acknowledged.
FAILED: svn: E200015: Operation cancelled
org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNCancelException: svn: E200015: Operation cancelled
    at hudson.scm.UserProvidedCredential$AuthenticationManagerImpl.checkIfProtocolCompleted(UserProvidedCredential.java:258)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.postCredential(SubversionSCM.java:2248)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doPostCredential(SubversionSCM.java:2192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:298)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:96)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:121)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:745)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:875)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:249)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:745)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:875)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:648)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:237)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at com.smartcodeltd.jenkinsci.plugin.assetbundler.filters.LessCSS.doFilter(LessCSS.java:46)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.plugins.greenballs.GreenBallFilter.doFilter(GreenBallFilter.java:58)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter$1.call(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:46)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.provideRequestDuring(ScmSyncConfigurationDataProvider.java:103)
    at hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration.extensions.ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.doFilter(ScmSyncConfigurationFilter.java:42)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:99)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I just took a closer look at [the documentation](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/SCM+Sync+configuration+plugin) and I saw this note:

[image]

It seems I should downgrade the Subversion plugin, which is not possible in the Jenkins 1.598 which I'm using! Downgrading Jenkins also may affect some other plugins! Has anyone noticed any better way to save Jenkins configuration files automatically on a server?

Comment: What version of SCM Sync Configuration and Subversion are you using?  Check `System Log` under `Manage Jenkins` and let me know if you see this error:  "aborted (scm manipulator not settled !)"

Comment: @lkisac please review my edits.

Comment: "SCM Repository has not yet been initiated !"  -  Have you authenticated your Subversion repository?  See my answer below. (includes the versions you need for both plugins and how to authenticate your repo)

Comment: @lkisac As I remember now, yes, I have authenticated! But since I'm in holidays now, I can't check it for sure! I'll do it ASAP and will try your answer and let you know about it! Thanks BTW!

Comment: @lkisac Please review my edits.

Comment: please try the versions I suggested for both plugins in my answer below

Comment: @lkisac Could you please tell me what Jenkins version I should use for the plugins' versions you've suggested? I use Jenkins Version 1.598 and the oldest version of subverion plugin is 1.24 there.

Comment: Check if the plugin versions I mentioned work with Jenkins 1.598.  If not, I was able to get it working with version 1.580.2.  If you want to use newer versions, I would suggest testing with the [LTS](http://jenkins-ci.org/content/jenkins-long-term-support-release) (Long-Term Support) releases of Jenkins.   Click 'Long Term Support Release' under 'Download Jenkins'.  Subversion plugin should be 1.54

Comment: Were you able to get the plugin to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try SCM Sync Configuration *0.0.7.3* and Subversion *1.54*.

Any newer releases of Subversion will not work.

I also tested the latest SCM Sync Configuration (0.8) and 0.0.7.4 - updates to system config will display the commit message popup, but not for job config updates.

I haven't tested without entering credentials in Subversion, but this would affect it as well.  So if you haven't authenticated, click the help (?) icon next to the Subversion textbox and click 'this link'.

[image: SCM Sync Configuration Subversion help]

Enter your Repository URL and authentication method.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the SVN repository URL with a browser on your Jenkins machine.  Make sure you're not seeing any SSL issues (expired certificate for instance).  Also you can set up a log to track this plugin by doing the following:

1. Jenkins, Manage Jenkins, System Log, Add new log recorder.
2. Name: SCM_Sync (or any name you like)
3. Logger: hudson.plugins.scm_sync_configuration
4. Log level: ALL
5. Click on "Save".

Try connecting again "you may have to add or remove a '/' to the end of the URL to get SCM Sync to try connecting again; look at the log for any additional in

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with my system.  You can downgrade the Subversion Plugin subversion.hpi file from the archive (next to the Latest Release, or http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/subversion/).

1. Download the subversion.hpi to the Jenkins Master server.
2. Install the subversion.hpi file on the master server into the
   ...Jenkins/war/WEB-INF/plugins/ subdirectory.
3. On the web browsers console, go to Jenkins, Manage Jenkins, and
   click the "Prepare for Shutdown" option.
4. Enter http://localhost:8080/restart on the browser URL, where
   "localhost" is the machine name or IP address of your jenkins master
   server.
5. Click the "Yes" button when prompted.  Jenkins will restart when the
   machine is not executing a build.

You should now have the downgraded Subversion plugin operating.  Check the Plugin list to verify.